# Create a Matcap from Textured Model

Tags: texturing, matcaps

Sometimes I see great materials, but they are not spheres, so I can't use it directly as a matcap. However, in some instances, the shape is simply enough (cylinder) that I could probably recreate the mesh and project the image onto it.

With the textured mesh, is there a way to generate a matcap?

Answer (score 2):

[matcap generator](http://bensimonds.com/2010/07/30/matcap-generator/)

This is a great matcap generator .blend from Ben Simonds.  I'd imagine you could simply apply a texture to the sphere and render it out.

Then, apply the matcap to your model using reflection coordinates, and go to textured view mode to see the results.