# Make blender viewer look like 3D Builder

Tags: 3d-view, matcaps

So ignoring the measurements and the reflective grid floor is there any way to make blenders viewport look like that of 3D Builder? Having shadows cast real time and the mesh being that nice perfect white?

3D Builder:

[image: 3D Builder]

Blender:

[image: Blender]

And I have already tried using a matcap and ambient to emulate the look; however, it is not the look that I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Matcap]

Unless of course, you can change the strength of the matcap to make the white on it much stronger, or even create a custom matcap.

Comment: Creating custom matcap is possible but it's not related to the shadows from the object. New engine in Blender 2.8 called Eevee allows to preview rendered object with shadows casted real time, maybe that's the nearest thing to what you want. Note that Eevee is in develorment currently

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to steer clear of EEVEE, just do to it being in development. Don’t want to have to deal with all the bugs and glitches with it. But thanks anyway. Could you possibly point me in the right direction as to where I could learn to make a custom matcap?

Comment: It should still work as [explained before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31629/create-a-matcap-from-textured-model). There are [resources](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256/can-matcaps-be-used-for-all-objects-and-not-just-selected-objects/554#554) for other already created matcaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Blender Game Engine

While waiting for EVEE, Clay Engine and other things that are currently under development, this should be somehow possible with the *good old* Blender Game Engine. Here's a possible result:

[image: image description here]

First step is to switch the Engine in the Info bar (usually is on the top of the screen).

**Real time shadow**

Add a Sun lamp to the scene and go to the Properties editor and open the Object Data tab (sun icon). You'll see options that differ from the ones exposed in Blender Internal. If you enable Shadow, you should immediately see the cast shadow in the viewport once you have set it to Material Shading mode.

Here's a summary of the fields you'll have to work with:

[image]

You can now tweak the parameters of the rendering of the shadow (color, resolution, algorithm,..) to fit your needs.

In my example I parented the light to the camera (notice the dotted line in the previous image) in order to make it move accordingly to the view and not fixed with the scene. So light always comes from top left regardless the point of view as it happens in 3D Builder.

**White material**

For the whiteness of the materials, it's now just a matter of picking the right shade of white as diffuse color, bump up the intensity, and if you are not satisfied, also adding some Emission (called Emit in the material editor).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been using blender for a while now, and to my knowledge, no, you cannot. The only way to do so currently is to preview in rendered mode, which is obviously not real-time. As previously mentioned, the closest you can get is with matcaps. At worst you can try using the BGE with spotlights to get shadows, but that will most likely be a real pain to setup and use (if it even yields satisfactory results).

The reason for this is that blender does not have a good real-time raster based render engine... YET. However, as we speak, there is one in development. It is called EEVEE, and if you are willing to try a slow and buggy version of an uncompleted blender, you can get it in blender 2.8 builds here https://builder.blender.org/download/. It attempts to solve this very issue. Be warned however, this is not a faithful representation of the experience expected from the completed 2.8.

If you are feeling even more adventurous, you can try to download another render engine for blender like armory http://armory3d.org/, however, I can not guaranty that it will be much better than eevee (and they often cost money).

Comment: Cheers, but I was hoping to steer clear of EEVEE due to its buggy nature

Comment: Cant blame you for that! Indeed, it is probably wisest to do so. I guess you could try to use the BGE, but it will most likely be a real pain to setup and use.

Comment: It's actually not hard to set it up with the BGE using textured view in the viewport. Simply use a sun lamp pointing straight down with a strength of 2 and shadow enabled and the buffer type set to variance, and also add a hemi pointing straight up with a strength of .5. Then set your material to be completely white with full intensity. You can also enable ambient occlusion on the viewport in the shading tab of the properties panel to make it look a bit better too.